# Mapping CName to Windows Azure

Tags: c#, windows, azure

I am running a site on Windows Azure:

mysite.azurewebsites.net

where my site is the name I was given. I mapped a cname to my site.azurewebsites.net. When I enter my CNAME in the browser, I get a 404. Are there any additional steps to map a CNAME to my site?

I know for an IIS site, I need to set-up a host name. Do I need to do this? I see no CNAME textbox in the preview portal.

Here is an image of my Websites > Configuration area:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

"I see no CNAME textbox in the preview portal." Look harder? It's there somewhere, and you do need to tell Windows Azure about the host name(s) you're doing to use.

(Sorry, I can't log in right now and look for exactly where it is.)

Comment: It's on the Web Site-> Configure -> hostnames section to help smarx out until he can login :) * Note support for custom domains are only for reserved mode Web Sites

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see it there. Please see my updated post.

Comment: Yup, it's right there in the screenshot ("Site URLs", under the "hostnames" section header.) Note that as @user728584 pointed out, you can only use custom domains if you're in "reserved mode."